# How to use .= in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, string-concatenation

I have some HTML like:

```
<div class="blah">
    <span class="fileName">1.jpg</span>
</div>
<div class="blah">
    <span class="fileName">2.jpg</span>
</div>
<div class="blah">
    <span class="fileName">3.jpg</span>
</div>
<div class="blah">
    <span class="fileName">4.jpg</span>
</div>
```

I want to get the file names with jQuery(a variable that stores smth like 1.jpg,2.jpg,3.jpg,4.jpg).

I finally could do it with an hidden input box, this is my working script:

```
<input type="hidden" id="img_names_input" />
<script>
$('.fileName').each(function(){
    var img_names_input = $(img_names_input).val();
    var img_names = $(this).html();
    $(img_names_input).val(img_names_input+','+img_names);
});
</script>
```

This is working just fine, but it doesn't seem a perfect solution to me, I'm just a learner, anybody could come up with a better solution? something like:

```
$('.fileName').each(function(){
        var img_names .= ',' + $(this).html();
        alert(img_names);
    });
```

or maybe some sort of array implementation here... !?
Thanks

Comment: `.=` is concatenation in PHP

Comment: why 3 negative points!? what is it?

Comment: [`.=` in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) vs [`+=` in Javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_operators.asp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This try this snippet. Might help you.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var img_names = [];
    $('.fileName').each(function(index){
        img_names.push($(this).html());     
    });
    alert(img_names);
});
```

Please note that `.=` wont work in javascript.

Comment: Use [] instead of new Array and push the content

Answer (score 3):

Use `+=` instead of `.=`.

You need `+` to concatenate in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript uses `+` to concatenate strings. I'd make an array:

```
var images = [];

$('.fileName').each(function() {
    images.push($(this).text());
});
```

Or with `.map()`:

```
var images = $('.fileName').map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
}).get();
```

Answer (score 1):

The code should instead be like:

```
var img_names = "";
$('.fileName').each(function() {
    img_names += $(this).html();
});
$('#img_names_input').val(img_names);
```